# Is there any research work on the possible data structures that can be used to represent an architectural design of a building?

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I am looking for a data structure, that can be used for description of a floor plan of a building. Its not about the format, I am asking about any other way to describe the floor plan of building, rather than in traditional map-based structure, preferably in some sort of tree or graph based structure, which can be derived from a text based description of the house.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about file formats

Comment: Its not about file-formats, its about how can the floor plan be described, rather than the conventional map-like structure.

Answer (score 1):

DXF in computer aided design should already allow this representation. I would suggest you to check the format and adapt your data structures accordingly.

Check the data structures in [LibDWG](http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/) and [LibDXF](https://github.com/bert/libdxf).

Comment: its not about the format, I am asking about any other way to describe the floor plan of building, rather than in traditional map-based structure, preferably in some sort of tree, or graph based structure, which can be derived from a text based description of the house.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at DXF.  It can do what you are looking for.  You can build tree structures in DXF.  Any library that handles dxf can also be used to create DXF objects in memory in a tree structure. Ezdxf (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezdxf/0.6.3) is one example of such a library.  You can add objects in a hierarchical way, so that the.  You must (of course) add attributes to the nodes to specify size, location, color, etc. of the nodes, but you can work with it structurally.  Take a look, see if it does what you need.  If it doesn't, then tell us what is missing or wrong.

Comment: I mean the same thing. Updated my answer.

Comment: @tbirdal - Yeah, sorry about that.  I meant that comment for shreelock, I should have tagged it correctly.  I understood what you meant, but was trying to push the point of it a little harder for shreelock.